# How do I implement dynamic text in iOS specifying both min and max font size restrictions?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

By dynamic text, I mean using this: (Check dynamic text in) https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/visual-design/typography/

I have gone through some similar questions. However none of them explain about both min and max. I want to put the restriction for uilabel, uitextfield both.

Comment: your question is not clear. add more details and what you tried.

Comment: You have answers for minimum so in your case the maximum would be default. Ergo it will be default if it has enough room otherwise it will shrink down to minimum. Or is there another logic in between?

Comment: Is there anyway I can restrict the maximum too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the minimum font size you can set it  from storyboard.
And for the maximum font size you need to check programatically like this-

```
let maxFontSize = 30
If label.font.pointSize > 30 {
    label.font = label.font.withSize(maxFontSize)
}
```

Also you can check minimum font with the same approach.